# Why is using StateDescriptor to set default state value deprecated?

Tags: apache-flink

I find the method `public ValueStateDescriptor(String name,TypeInformation<T> typeInfo,T defaultValue)`is now deprecated and the documentation says to manage the default value by checking whether the contents of the state is null.
I wonder what does this suggestion for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [FLINK-5155](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5155) which introduced the deprecation:

> Having the default value in the descriptor is problematic with some
>   serialisers and we don't lose a feature because users can always check
>   for the null value and initialise with their own default value if
>   necessary. Right now, we're always forcing people to specify a default
>   value even though they don't need one.

And the corresponding PR: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/3108

Answer (score 1):

Further, if you're using this in a (Rich)Function, you should check for null in the following way, in your primary function like `map()` or `flatMap()`, not `open()`:

```
if( state.value() == null ) {
  state.update(...defaultValue...);
}
```

`open()` doesn't care for using `state.update()` within.

Comment: what if state hold a primitive value(such as scala.Int, scala.Double)? stat.value() == null will always to be false.